# Subtract from a running quantity based off values in multiple rows (SQL)

Tags: sql, loops, ssms, common-table-expression

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will do a few things, but i'll start with the easiest first:

I have a group of objects with IDs (in this example, different colors of marbles).  My query will SUM these marbles and result in a table like this:

| marbles | number_of_marbles |
| --- | --- |
| Green Marble | 50 |

Then, I have a table of baskets where I want to drop these marbles into.  The quantity in this table represents how many are needed to satisfy a full basket of marbles.

| basket | required_marbles | marble_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| basket_one | 60 | Green Marble |
| basket_two | 30 | Green Marble |

The end result is that I want to prioritize filling a basket with the least amount of required marbles. The reason is if I can fill up a basket, I can set aside and remove from table eventually.

The desired output in this case would be:

| basket | required_marbles | marble_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| basket_one | 40 | Green Marble |
| basket_two | 0 | Green Marble |

I used a CTE provided by a previous answer but ran into a slight issue:

```
select top 1 @number_of_marbles = number_of_marbles from @marbles
        ;with cte as (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [required_marbles] asc
        ) as rno from @required_marbles_table),

            cte1(rno,tot) as (select top 1 rno, @number_of_marbles-required_marbles as tot from cte t
            union all select t.rno, tot-required_marbles as tot from cte t,cte1  where (t.rno-1)=cte1.rno
            )
            update t set required_marbles=(case when tot>0 then 0 else -tot end) from cte t inner join cte1 on t.rno=cte1.rno
        
            select * from @required_marbles_table
```

In this case, the result is correct (i.e. look at desired output table). However, if the quantity wouldn't 0 out a row (i.e. if number_of_marbles is actually 5 for example), the number is subtracted from every single row.

| basket | required_marbles | marble_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| basket_one | 55 | Green Marble |
| basket_two | 25 | Green Marble |

**That's the 'easy' part**

The other piece I would like to add is, if you have two different types of marbles.

| marbles | number_of_marbles |
| --- | --- |
| Green Marble | 50 |
| Blue Marble | 30 |

and I want to fill up some baskets:

| basket | required_marbles | marble_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| basket_one | 60 | Green Marble |
| basket_two | 30 | Green Marble |
| basket_three | 50 | Blue Marble |

I would like to be able to use the 'new' code to loop through based off marble color and allocate to it's respective basekt.
End result being something like:

| basket | required_marbles | marble_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| basket_one | 40 | Green Marble |
| basket_two | 0 | Green Marble |
| basket_three | 20 | Blue Marble |

Comment: Probably you will need a [recursive query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL), something like in [this Oracle dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2YXzAIjx).

Comment: ... or  [simpler](https://dbfiddle.uk/fNNoRnTr)

Comment: @PonderStibbons I was able to do this w/ a cte, however, please post your answer locally so I can accept it as an answer as it was a great solution to the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use your environment, but as this question is marked with SQL tag I made two solutions in Oracle. They are close to standard SQL, so can be easily adapted to your needs, I hope. First solution uses only analytic sum and some logic with `greatest` and `least`:

```
select basket, type, req, amt, 
       least(greatest(
         sum(req) over (partition by type order by req, basket) - amt, 
         0), req) result
  from baskets join marbles using(type) order by type desc, basket
```

Second solution uses recursive query:

```
with base as (
  select basket, type, req, amt, 
         row_number() over (partition by type order by req, basket) rn
  from baskets b join marbles using (type) ),
r(rn, basket, type, req, amt) as (
  select rn, basket, type, greatest(req - amt, 0), 
         greatest(amt - req, 0) 
  from base where rn = 1
  union all
  select r.rn + 1, b.basket, b.type, greatest(b.req - r.amt, 0), 
         greatest(r.amt - b.req, 0) 
  from r join base b on b.rn = r.rn + 1 and b.type = r.type )
select basket, type, req from r order by type desc, basket;
```

dbfiddles for both solutions: [fiddle 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/fNNoRnTr) and [fiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/2YXzAIjx)